# LM2776 Inverter is not producing -3.3v with 3.3v input

Tags: dc-dc-converter, charge-pump

### Background

I am using a TI LM2776 Switched Capacitor Inverter ([datasheet here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2776.pdf)) to obtain a -3.3v bias voltage for an LCD (Newhaven Display, NHD-12864MZ-FSW-GBW-L, [datasheet here](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/specs/NHD-12864MZ-FSW-GBW-L.pdf)).

The LM2776 is connected exactly as shown in this digram from its datasheet:

[image: LM2776 Typical Application]

Vin is 3.3v, EN is connected to Vin, and I'm using the same capacitor values.

### Question

When I turn on the circuit with no load, the output of the LM2776 is about -0.9v. When I connect it to the LCD bias pin to load it, the output is about -0.7v. Why am I not seeing about -3.3v?

### Other Notes

**LCD Load**

When I connect the LCD bias voltage pin to a DC power supply (at -3.3v) instead of the LM2776, the LCD draws about 20mA, so the LCD should be an appropriate load for the LM2776. According to the datasheet, I shouldn't be seeing any significant voltage drop at this current draw:

[image: LM2776 Vout vs Iout]

**Capacitors**

All capacitors are ceramic X7R radial capacitors.

**Layout**

The circuit is currently on a breadboard, and the LM2776 is connected to it through a SOT23-6 -> DIP adapter. I know these devices can be sensitive to layout considerations, but the same configuration worked a couple of weeks ago, and I have no reason to suspect there was damage of any kind done to it since then.

[image: LM2776 Breadboard]

Comment: Pictures of your circuit layout and details about the capacitors would be appropriate, as switching converters are sensitive to these things.

Comment: @uint128_t Added.

Comment: @uint128_t I know they're sensitive, but since I've gotten it to work before, I thought I was set. Can you think of any reason they may have worked before when they probably shouldn't have?

Comment: What kind of power supply are you using for the 3.3V? Can you confirm it fulfills the current supply specifications for LM2776 (EN=1) and for the LCD?

Comment: Can you get a scope plot at the C1+ pin (or anywhere on that net)? I would be suspicious that the device is not switching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The breadboard prototype of this circuit *did* work a couple of times, (maybe 3 out of 50 tries), but those may have just been flukes that mislead me into thinking that something must have changed to make it not work anymore.

When I assembled the circuit on a PCB with all surface-mount capacitors that adhere to the layout recommendations given in the LM2776 datasheet, it works 100% of the time.

I suspect uin28_t's comment was on the right track - the through-hole capacitor leads and DIP adaptor for the IC introduced enough impedance for the LM2776 to be unable to maintain the correct voltage, and I just got lucky the rare times it did work.

Comment: **"When I assembled the circuit on a PCB with all surface-mount capacitors that adhere to the layout recommendations given in the LM2776 datasheet, it works 100% of the time."** This, exactly. Just worked on a similar problem with the LM2776; having all three capacitors too far away lowered the output voltage to -2.0v when +5.0v was used as a supply and no load on output. Moving them directly next to the LM2776 using 0805 SMTs worked.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested layout at section 10.2 of the datasheet does not match the part pinout in section 5!  I have been through much grief finding this out.
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2776.pdf

Comment: Do you mean sections 5 and **8**.2? I remember being confused by that, but 10.2 and 5 match.